# browserify/webpack break simple HTML file (function is not defined)

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, browserify

I have the below index.html file:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>


num1:<input id="num1" type="number">
num2:<input id="num2" type="number">



<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">compute</button>

answer:<input id="demoInput" type="text"> and answer: <p 
id="demoHtml"></p>

</body>

<script src="index.js"></script>
```

where index.js is

```
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("num1").value;
var y = document.getElementById("num2").value;
var ans = parseInt(x) + parseInt(y)
document.getElementById("demoInput").value = ans;
document.getElementById("demoHtml").innerHTML = ans;
}
```

This above code works perfectly. Using webpack/browserify poses difficulties in the following way. If I call

```
browserify index.js > bundle.js
```

then edit the index.html file to read

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

and run the index.html file, the browser console in developer tools shows the following error upon pressing the compute button:

```
index.html:14 Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined at 
HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:14)
```

Webpack presents the same challenge. Perhaps I am implementing webpack and browserify incorrectly? Searching online has yielded little insight.

Answer (score 2):

Since "myFunction" now lies inside a module, you have to make it visible somehow.

try to use the [global](https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook#global) object:

```
global.myFunction = function () {
// ...
}
```

then it should be visible to the html again.